# I am not able to access phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, ubuntu-12.04

When trying to access phpMyAdmin, this is the error message I receive: Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error MySQL said: Documentation

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running another MYSQL Server instance

Comment: Might be running a MYSQL Workbench Instance? _If_ so, disable it first.

Comment: reading the error would be a good start: `the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration`

Comment: what's the context? is it a fresh installation and your first attempt? or has everything worked out nicely before, and now the world suddenly exploded?

Comment: Its a fresh installation

Answer (score 1):

Check \xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php on line 23

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

all authentication will be below

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Then  Restart XAMPP

Also you can check here

xampp/htdocs/xampp/cds.php

```
check line 4 to: mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
and line 78 to: if(!mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
```

Comment: Yeah its there but i still am denied

Comment: do you have mysqli enabled in your PHP?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Open root XAMPP file directory C:/XAMPP/phpmyadmin/config.inc and scroll down to :

```
27   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
28   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

> 2.Edit "127.0.0.1" of line 27 to localhost with your port number as in e.g localhost:80.

Result :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:80';
```

> 3.Remove pma from , ['controluser'] = 'pma'.

Result:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '';
```

Then finally attempt access with localhost or refresh page. Happy =]D